# Expectation of the max of $M$ i.i.d. Gumbel with scale different from $1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

I am looking for the expression of the expected value of the max  $M$ i.i.d. Gumbel $\epsilon_i$ with scale $\beta$ and location $\mu$. I found the answer to this question when $\beta=1$ (e.g., [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192424/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-iid-gumbel-variables)). I am looking for the case in which $\beta\neq 1$. When $\beta=1$
$$
\mathbb{E}(\max_{i\in \{1,...,M\}} \epsilon_i+ a_i) = \mu+\gamma+\log[\sum_{i=1}^M \exp(a_i+\mu)]
$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Could you confirm that when $\beta\neq 1$ we get
$$
\mathbb{E}(\max_{i\in \{1,...,M\}} \epsilon_i+ a_i) = \mu+\beta\gamma+\beta\log[\sum_{i=1}^M \exp(\frac{a_i+\mu}{\beta})]
$$
?